# Programmatically Removing N2 CMS Nodes from the Trash

Tags: c#, n2cms

Within N2 CMS, is there a way to programmatically remove nodes from the trash?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: according to source code there a possibility to do a `Restore` for items in the trash.

Comment: Not looking to restore.  Looking to remove / delete from trash.

Comment: You can purge the items contained in the trash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In this example models of type TargetDetailModel are being permanently deleted from the N2 CMS trash.

```
var trash = new ItemList<TrashContainerItem>(N2.Find.RootItem.Children, new TypeFilter(typeof(TrashContainerItem))).FirstOrDefault();
if (trash != null)
{
  var detailToPermDelete = new ItemList<TargetDetailModel>(trash.Children, new TypeFilter(typeof(TargetDetailModel)));
  for (int permDeleteCount = 0; permDeleteCount < detailToPermDelete.Count; permDeleteCount++)
  {                            
    N2.Context.Current.Persister.Delete(detailToPermDelete.ElementAt(permDeleteCount));
  }
}
```